# How to calculate the dates for last four sundays from current date

Tags: php, mysql, date

How can we get the dates of last four sundays with respect to the current date in mysql? Thanks,

Lets say today's date is `12/14/2012` so output from the `sql` query should look like following

```
1st Sunday  | 2nd Sunday  |  3rd Sunday  |  4rth Sunday
11/11/2012    18/11/2012     25/11/2012     09/12/2012
```

**UPDATE:**

With PHP I did this:

```
    $date_lastsunday = strtotime("last Sunday");
$w1_sunday = $date_lastsunday - 7 * 24 * 3600;
$w2_sunday = $date_lastsunday - 14 * 24 * 3600;
$w3_sunday = $date_lastsunday - 21 * 24 * 3600;
$w4_sunday = $date_lastsunday - 28 * 24 * 3600;
```

Wondering how it can be done with mysql...

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), please.

Comment: Post here your efforts...what you did to get last four sundays....

Comment: @JohnConde i tried `select date_sub(curdate(), interval 7 day , select date_sub(curdate(), interval 14 day` but they are not accurate in terms of current date

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want them in each single row

```
SELECT Curdate() - INTERVAL (Weekday(Curdate())+1) day AS `Sunday` 
UNION 
SELECT Curdate() - INTERVAL (Weekday(Curdate())+1+7*1) day 
UNION 
SELECT Curdate() - INTERVAL (Weekday(Curdate())+1+7*2) day 
UNION 
SELECT Curdate() - INTERVAL (Weekday(Curdate())+1+7*3) day
```

If you want them in column, replace `UNION SELECT` with `,`. Like this

```
SELECT Curdate() - INTERVAL (Weekday(Curdate())+1) day `1st Sunday`, 
       Curdate() - INTERVAL (Weekday(Curdate())+1+7*1) day `2nd Sunday`, 
       Curdate() - INTERVAL (Weekday(Curdate())+1+7*2) day `3rd Sunday`, 
       Curdate() - INTERVAL (Weekday(Curdate())+1+7*3) day `4th Sunday`
```

A **less cpu intensive** way,

```
SET @OFS=Weekday(Curdate())+1;
SET @CD=curdate();
sELECT @CD - INTERVAL (@OFS) day `1st Sunday`, 
       @CD - INTERVAL (@OFS+7*1) day `2nd Sunday`, 
       @CD - INTERVAL (@OFS+7*2) day `3rd Sunday`, 
       @CD - INTERVAL (@OFS+7*3) day `4th Sunday`
```